# creating db table with foreign key ANDROID

Tags: android, sqlite

Im trying to created a db that (at the moment) has 4 tables `{USERS,TOPICS,GROUPS,CREATED_TOPICS}`. I keep getting this error when i try and run it...

> syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table
>   created_topics_table (CREATED_TOPIC_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
>   AUTOINCREMENT, TOPIC_ID INTEGER,USER_ID INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(TOPIC_ID)
>   REFERENCES topics_table(_ID),FOREIGN KEY(USER_ID) REFERENCES
>   users_table(_ID).

heres the code...

```
public class databaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
//DATABASE NAME
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "users.db";
//USERS TABLE
public static final String TABLE_NAME_USERS = "users_table";
public static final String COL_USER_ID = "_ID";
public static final String COL_USER_NAME = "USER_NAME";
public static final String COL_USER_EMAIL = "USER_EMAIL";
public static final String COL_USER_PASSWORD = "USER_PASSWORD";
//TOPICS TABLE
public static final String TABLE_NAME_TOPICS = "topics_table";
public static final String COL_TOPIC_ID = "_ID";
public static final String COL_TOPIC_NAME = "TOPIC_NAME";


//GROUPS TABLE
public static final String TABLE_NAME_GROUPS = "groups_table";
public static final String COL_GROUP_ID = "GROUP_ID";
public static final String COL_GROUP_NAME = "GROUP_NAME";

public static final String TABLE_NAME_CREATED_TOPICS =
"created_topics_table";
public static final String COL_CREATED_TOPIC_ID = "CREATED_TOPIC_ID";
public static final String COL_FK_TOPIC_TOPIC_ID = "TOPIC_ID";
public static final String COL_FK_TOPIC_USER_ID = "USER_ID";

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME_USERS + " (_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY   
AUTOINCREMENT,USER_NAME TEXT,USER_EMAIL TEXT,USER_PASSWORD TEXT)");
db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME_TOPICS + " (_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY     
AUTOINCREMENT,TOPIC_NAME TEXT)");
db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME_GROUPS + " (GROUPS_ID INTEGER PRIMARY    
KEY AUTOINCREMENT,GROUP_NAME TEXT)");
db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME_CREATED_TOPICS + " (CREATED_TOPIC_ID 
INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TOPIC_ID INTEGER,USER_ID INTEGER, FOREIGN
KEY(TOPIC_ID) REFERENCES " +TABLE_NAME_TOPICS + "(_ID)," +                                                                                                                                                            
"FOREIGN KEY(USER_ID) REFERENCES " +TABLE_NAME_USERS + "(_ID)");
}
```

Comment: which DB are you using? shouldn't  `AUTOINCREMENT` be `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Comment: AUTOINCREMENT works, no need for the underscore, and im just using the bulit in sqlite db

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed closing parentheses at the end:

```
create table created_topics_table (CREATED_TOPIC_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TOPIC_ID INTEGER,USER_ID INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(TOPIC_ID) REFERENCES topics_table(_ID),FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID) REFERENCES users_table(_ID))
```

One other note on sqlite foreign keys. They are off by default. You need to use `"PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON"` every time you open database connection

**EDIT**

Change:

```
db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME_CREATED_TOPICS + " (CREATED_TOPIC_ID 
INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TOPIC_ID INTEGER,USER_ID INTEGER, FOREIGN
KEY (TOPIC_ID) REFERENCES " +TABLE_NAME_TOPICS + " (_ID)," +                                                                    
"FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID) REFERENCES " +TABLE_NAME_USERS + " (_ID))");
```

Comment: how do i set the PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON? i get an cannot resolve symbol 'PRAGMA'...Any example?

Comment: db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON");

Comment: everything ran fine but when i ran a query to show some data from the table it said  no such table: TABLE_NAME_CREATED_TOPICS. any idea? thanks alot for your help.

Comment: @luke your table didn't get created because of the syntax error in your SQL statement. I corrected that. see the EDIT section of the answer

Comment: @luke  use below function before any database operation                      
 private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
  
  public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase(DatabaseHelper db) {
             
    if(db.isOpen()){
    dataBase.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
     return dataBase;
    }
   
    
        dataBase = db.getWritableDatabase();
        dataBase.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");

        return dataBase;
    }

Answer (score 1):

Add a space between **FOREIGN KEY(TOPIC_ID) REFERENCES topics_table(_ID),** and **FOREIGN KEY(USER_ID)**

(CREATED_TOPIC_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TOPIC_ID INTEGER,USER_ID INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(TOPIC_ID) REFERENCES topics_table(_ID), FOREIGN KEY(USER_ID) REFERENCES users_table(_ID)

use this hope it will work.